# Angular 6 datatable serverside ajax request not working

Tags: ajax, angular, datatables-1.10, angular-datatables

I am using angular datatable(1.10.19). 
[ref this for server side angular way](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/server-side-angular-way)

I have written web api in c# to get the data in desired format.
With following dtoptions, server side is working fine.

```
dtOptions = {
                    pagingType: 'full_numbers',
                    pageLength: 10,
                    processing: true,
                    serverSide: true,
                    orderCellsTop: true,
                    ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {

                        this.mainpageservice.GetPaginatedData(this.menuID, this.UserName, dataTablesParameters)
                            .subscribe(resp => {
                                this.Module = resp.data;
                                console.log('serverside', this.Module);
                                callback({
                                    recordsTotal: resp.recordsTotal,
                                    recordsFiltered: resp.recordsFiltered,
                                    data: [],
                                });
                            });
                    },
```

Now, I want to display multiple tables that too using serverside angular way datatable. so to achieve this, I am using: [for multiple datatables](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/multiple-tables)

as documented, I have created one function which is returning Datatable settings. But here ajax call is not working.

Can anyone suggest where I am doing wrong?.

```
    private buildDtOptions(menu: number, Username: string): DataTables.Settings  {
    alert('call');
    return {
        pagingType: 'full_numbers',
        pageLength: 10,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        orderCellsTop: true,
        ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
            console.log(dataTablesParameters);
            this.mainpageservice.GetPaginatedData(menu, Username, dataTablesParameters).subscribe(resp => {
                    this.Module = resp.data;
                    console.log('serverside', this.Module);
                    callback({
                        recordsTotal: resp.recordsTotal,
                        recordsFiltered: resp.recordsFiltered,
                        data: [],
                    });
                });
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? Not executed?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you ran into the same issue that I did or not, but when I was moving to the "Server side the Angular way" from the "Angular Way", I forgot to remove the `dtTrigger` reference from the markup. Once I removed `[dtTrigger]="dtTrigger"` from the table tag all was good in my world.